# LDAP Tomcat implementation

Tags: jsp, ldap, struts, tomcat8

I need to implement LADP + Tomcat plan as described [here](http://blog.mc-thias.org/?title=tomcat_ldap_authentication&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), where they have given an *index.jsp*.

I believe a user needs to give username and password and these will be compared with the LDAP username and password. For me, if login is successful, it has to go *mainPage.jsp*. Normally, we will have  `action="\loginAction"` and in *struts-config.xml*, we mention about success on the page *mainPage.jsp*. But here the action is different. How does it find my *mainPage.jsp*?

Also, I'm confused by this:

```
j_username, j_password, action='<%= response.encodeURL("j_security_check") %>'
```

Comment: Which LDAP server did you use?